# Save Japanese string to the mysql 8.0 database

Tags: database-design, mysql-8.0, collation, encoding, international-components-unicode

To accept Japanese strings and save them in MySQL 8.0, I setup the field with the utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci collation, but on some strings, it returns the "Conversion from collation utf8_general_ci into utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci is impossible for parameter" error.The code is written in Golang using GoRM for queries.
I tried to change the collation in the database column which cause problem.